# Visual studio code java debug not working

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am on macOS high sierra using vscode 
I am trying to debug a java program i opened from a regular folder 
but when i click the debug button the debugger just lingers and doesn't start up, i also tried f5 and that does not work either

**Screenshot**

[image]

I also saw that for c programs needed to be compiled with the -g flag so i added that in a tasks.json i made

`"tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "javac",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "Main.java"
            ]
        }
    ]`

Comment: dont know how to solve your problem, but you can give Intellij idea a chance. Probably best java IDE

Comment: i would use an ide for big projects but want an editor like vscode for smaller programs

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with VS, but my recommendations are as follows:
1. Opening the file in another IDE which is more compatible with Java. (Then you'll know if it's the file or the IDE itself that's the issue).
2. Compile using terminal and see what happens. (On High Sierra, there are some compiling issues with some Java code at the moment, mainly with `showSaveDialog()` methods but you never know).
3. If the first 2 past, then reinstall VS and JDK. You could have had some issues during installation that Mac might have overlooked or just plain ignore.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yea on the term it turns fine, theres just a problem making the vscode debugger recognize the java to debug it, i wanna uninstall vscode as a last resort cuz i already have some settings saved there